# Submit form with input added in the URL and not as parameter

Tags: python, django, forms

Supposing I have the following Form. Is there a better way to send the value of the input in the URL like in the example "`indication_effects/+MY_VALUE`" and get rid of the parameter `indication=MY_VALUE` ?

Maybe it is possible to do it with Django or should I simply use a django form?

Thank you,

```
          <form id="indication-form" class="form-horizontal" method="get">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indication-input" name="indication" />

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="indication-submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

var indicationForm = $('#indication-form');

$("#indication-submit").on("click", function () {
    indicationForm.attr("action", "indication_effects/" + $("#indication-input").val());
    indicationForm.submit();
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django. You can accomplish it using plain Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: Sure but it looks ugly..

Answer (score 0):

Look, the `GET` request **always** will send the form data through url and the `POST` request **always** will send the form data through request headers.

It may not look pretty, but it's the way it works.

**However**, you can do something nice with [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) to get what you want.

Disregard your form `action`, change your submit button from `<button>` to `<a>` and build its `href` dynamically, you can "submit" your form using the form data on your HTML.

Something like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <form id="indication-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action=".">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indication-input" name="indication" v-model="indication" />

                <a :href="getUrl" class="btn btn-primary" id="indication-submit">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="//unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            indication: '' // Link all your form fields with v-model here
        },
        computed: {
            getUrl: function() {
                return '/' + this.indication + '/'; // Build your url
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Vue.js is a powerful and simple Javascript framework, I like it very much.